# iOpus iMacros script for simple URL scrape

Tags: firefox-addon, web-scraping, imacros

Trying to exctract a link url with iMacros for Firefox plugin.

The following **input** html code is on the website to be scraped: a link url and a description

```
<div class="subcl">
    <a href="http://www.url.com/someurl.html" target="_blank">description</a>
</div>
```

Desired **output** from iMacros: simply the link url

```
http://www.url.com/someurl.html
```

Since there are further links on the website the class="subcl" should be included in the code. Maybe there is a way to implement a nested structure?  I would prefer - if possible - non Javascript code since I don't code in it myself.

The following **macro code didn't work**

```
VERSION BUILD=8300326 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1

'Open the website
URL GOTO=http://www.url.com/pagetobescraped.html

'Extract the link url on the page
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:subcl* EXTRACT=HREF
```

The macro returns `#EANF#` (end of file reached with no match).  When I replace `EXTRACT=HREF` with `EXTRACT=TXT` it returns `"description"` but I need the URL.

---

**Edit**

to clarify symbiotech's answer:  the input html code is preceeded by the elements `<h1>` as well as `<p>`.  All togehter it looks like this ...

```
<h1>Title of the page</h1><p class="intro"></p>

<div class="subcl">
    <a href="http://www.url.com/someurl.html" target="_blank">description</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to extract the `href` from an `a` elem, not from the `div` itself. Also since you say there're other links on the page you need to take as a reference point every "sublc" `div`, hence the `POS=R1`:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:subcl*
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=HREF
```

If you need multiple links extracted instead use "Play Loop" button with this:

```
TAG POS={{!LOOP}} TYPE=DIV ATTR=CLASS:subcl*
TAG POS=R1 TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=HREF
```

**EDIT** for your specific case:
You need to position yourself above the elements you want to extract, but on the same tree level in order to use relative positioning proper. That empty `p` elem seems a good enough anchor or you could use the `h1` element, if its text doesn't change too much:

```
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:intro
TAG POS=R{{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=TXT
TAG POS=1 TYPE=P ATTR=CLASS:intro
TAG POS=R{{!LOOP}} TYPE=A ATTR=TXT:* EXTRACT=HREF
```

Comment: It seems iMacros doesn't accept `DIV` as a reference point if the relative link is contained in it.

Comment: yes you are correct, relative positioning doesn't work anymore with contained tags. please see my edit.

Comment: Thank you, that works! Just what I was looking for.  I've adjusted my question to clarify your answer.  Regarding iOpus I think it's counterintuitive to not allow relative positioning ... but oh well.